# Closing of a split pane very slow

Tags: excel, vba

I am at a loss and need your crowd inteligence.

For my music repertoire I created a workbook with a songlist, that I have automated with some useful macros. Basically I can filter the songlist, open youtube videos to the song on youtube and also have put the chord sheets in the workbook, that I also can access from the central "songlist" worksheet. For convinience of stepping through the titles and show the chord charts at the same time I made use of the create new window (pane) and grouped those 2 windows vertically. That was a little bit fuzzy and trial and error until I had it function the way I wanted. The code is not so pretty - but it worked as intended.

The full file is at the moment around 600K bit and contains approximately 50 sheets with only text data. I would think that is nothing excel would get sweaty about.

As to step through the titles from the songslist I entered the code in the Worksheet_SelectionChange event so I can easily step down with the arrow keys to get the next chordsheet. This should placed right next to the songlist. Assuming there is already a second window of the same workbook open, I have this close function in the code - if nothing was open yet, the on error resume next catches that case.

For some reason the code runs in the normal usage of the automated songlist sheet incredibly slow (nearly 10 seconds on a modern laptop with I7 intel core).
When I debug the code it runs quick - now brakes, not waiting - every command seems to be executed instantly. The big question is, why the worksheet does not match the performance in exceution during Worksheet_SelectionChange event. The code I have under suspicion is yellow marked. During the worksheet event I realize, that the closing of the second pane with the chordsheets takes long. In debugging it works like a breeze (quick).

Please find the code snippet of the Worksheet_SelectionChange event procedure and the MSO version I am using.

Last finding on this: Closing of the pane is slow, but so is any other small workbook.

Hope one of you can come up with an idea - I am at a loss now!

Cheers
Stefan

The code is closing a pane (from a split window).
I attach a code snippet
[image]

a screenshot of the excel frontend
[image]

and of my MS Office 365 version
[image]

Comment: There are a few problems with your code that are being hidden because of your use of `On Error Resume Next`. Replace it with `On Error GoTo errExit` and add a line label `errExit:` immediately before the second `With Application` then use breakpoints to step through your code. Also, if you do not have `Option Explicit` at the top of your Module then you should add it as the absence of this can also hide errors. Then try to compile then try to run your code with the breakpoints in place. If you need further help, please post your code as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks John for your debugging tipps.

In the meantime I found the reason for the extreme delay - although I don´t understand why it intermingles with the performance of what I do.

I have defined an alternative start-up folder in the options dialog. There are 2 addins , that I what to have started right form the begin of the excel session. THIS is causing all the trouble!

Deleting this alternative entry or also deleting the files there in fixes all performance issues here!

Why is closing a second window of a workbook such a deal and impacted be the alternative start-up folder? Amazing.....

​Guess that´s it for this thread.

In fact, I don´t get the pane (window) in the vertical algintment activated as I would like. The focus is always on the wrong side :(

If any tip is available here - I would be delighted.

Cheers

Stefan